# Send data as a response from nodejs server to html page so display it in table format

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html-table, frontend

I'm new to programming, I'm trying to build a web app using nodejs/expressjs.
so basically on the post route, after some processing on backend it gives an **array of object** in result variable, I want to use this result variable data and construct a **table in html file** and send this  table.html file as a response to client

the problem I'm encountering is how can I use this result variable to add element of table in html file dynamically (since array size changes everytime )

approach i was using

1. i created table.html and table.js that is linked with same html file.. but when table.html is send as a response that html file and table.js file is rendered on client side and not able to pass the result value that i get from server to that table.js file ( i get a document not defined error)
2. i tried to use EJS template .. how to create a function that used ejs variable to loop through array data and show table.. i'm unable to do

if anyone can help me to show `result=[{name:'james', id:23},{name:'joe',id:35}]`
to html file as response

main.js

```js
app.post('/dataTbale',(req,res) => {
  // after some processing i get array of obj that i store in result variable
  const result=[{name:'james', id:23},{name:'joe',id:35}];
  res.send('table.html);
})
```

table.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>table</h2>
    <div id="show_table"></div>
    <script src="table.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

table.js

```
const tableDiv=document.queryselector('#show_tabel');

result.forEach((obj) => {  //<==== i want to pass that result data here.
  tableDiv.innerHTML += result;
});
```

P.S just want to know if this works then i can create table

Comment: As I understand what u want in server-side-rendering (SSR). There are many ways to do this. You can check some tutorials to get started

Comment: I would import that JS that builds the html table into the same file that makes the request to the server and handles the response. Then I would pass the response as a parameter to the javascript function you've imported that generates/builds the table. That function would then update the DOM with the new elements (you can use the DOM api for this or a library like React that would just rerender the component after passing down certain props, like the number of rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a template engine like (ejs) or any other template engines to show the dynamic data that returns back from the server and for the case that you want to render the results in different page you should store the data in any kind of storages like local storage or database to be able to use it in different places.

Comment: yes i tried to use EJS and
```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const dummylist = [1, 2, 3, 44, 3];
  res.render("index", { listvalue: dummylist });
});
```
``` index.view file
<script>
    document.write("<h2><%=listvalue%></h2>");
  </script>
```

and it is rendering the value and printing it in index page  but passing a array of object it is not working

Comment: You should send the array of object back to the front-end like how you did it in this example  and then you can use one of the JavaScript build in methods like (array.map) to access the data inside that array.

Comment: is there not any way i can modify DOM from nodejs so that i just have to pass html file to response and client browser can show the data

Comment: Of course no because NodeJS is a sever side JavaScript and DOM is related to client side.